# Newbie in Android NDK: definition in Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new in Android NDK. I know in every **jni/** folder, there is **Android.mk** file, seems it always start with:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```

It defines the `LOCAL_PATH`, but if translate it to a human-readable launguage, what is this path? Is the `LOCAL_PATH` points to the **jni/** folder or is it the project root ?

For example, I imported an Android project which uses NDK, I checked its **Android.mk** file, it has something like following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
...
MY_PLUGINS := XXX YYY ZZZ

MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/other/something
```

**Question 1**, what does `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)` mean, what is the path it points to?

**Question 2**, Where can I find those `MY_PLUGINS`, I mean the XXX , YYY and ZZZ, at least I am not able to see it in the project I imported.

**Question 3**, Where can I find `something` defined by `MYPATH` ? I don't see it in project either.

P.S.:  (I tried to find it under **jni/other/something** , but there isn't such file). By the way, what is the name of the script language used in **Android.mk** ?

Comment: I think you are defining those variables

Comment: @blackbelt, I don't understand your comment, I know people define those things of course. My question is what is the rule, since I am not able to find those files defined in Android.mk in the project I imported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best resource here is probably the NDK documentation itself. It is (unfortunately) not hosted on the web, but it is distributed with the NDK. Check the `android-ndk-rX/documentation.html` file in the NDK you downloaded.

*Question 1*: from the `Android.mk File` part of the doc:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> An Android.mk file must begin with the definition of the LOCAL_PATH variable. It is used to locate source files in the development tree. In this example, the macro function 'my-dir', provided by the build system, is used to return the path of the current directory (i.e. the directory containing the Android.mk file itself).

*Question 2 and 3*: these variables are not "usual" variables in an `Android.mk` file. They are user-defined variables, and without more details on the project you're using, it's hard to tell much about it. For all I know, `MY_PATH` should indeed point to `jni/other/something`.

Concerning your *P.S.*, I don't think the Android.mk file is written in any particular known language: it's a custom language that has *some similarities* with Makefile.

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: There are a lot of Android.mk files in the AOSP source code. Could you please tell which on e are you referring to ?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the definition of how `my-dir` is evaluated is given in `build/core/definitions.mk` file in the AOSP source code. However, it doesn't have the wording which you quoted above. The name of the file would be useful because it can be used to find out other definitions too.

Answer (score 4):

Q - 1

Android.mk file must begin with LOCAL_PATH variable initialization.

LOCAL_PATH contains the "path to the Android.mk make file", in most case it would be present working directory.

$(call my-dir) is calling macro function "my-dir", defined in /build/core/definitions.mk, you can check the definition of the macro, It finds the directory for ndk-build script to start working.

Q - 2

Android.mk allows users to define local variables and "MY_PLUGINS" is a local variable containing list of plugins, "XXX YYY ZZZ" is list of the plugins he/she might be using within the Android.mk file.

Following are the restrictions on defining a local variable

1. Names that begin with LOCAL_ (e.g. LOCAL_MODULE)
2. Names that begin with PRIVATE_, NDK_ or APP_ (used internally)
3. Lower-case names (used internally, e.g. my-dir)

It is advised to use MY_ prefix for local variable definition

Q - 3

Again MY_PATH is a local variable which contains absolute path to the "/something/other" folder, now this path could contain "XXX YYY ZZZ" plugins or some other useful stuff.

Hope this helps